# Read data from Azure with different Class names

Tags: azure, windows-8, azure-mobile-services

With this code I'm able to read data from my Azure Web Service table.

```
private MobileServiceCollectionView<Item> items;
private IMobileServiceTable<Item> table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>();

items = table.ToCollectionView();
// and so on...
```

My problem is, that my table has a different name than the `Item` Class but I do not want to change the name of the table because I think it is the best name for the best understanding. Is it possible that my table has the name `Person` but I send my query with the Class name `Item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
//over the Class definition
[DataContract(Name = "*tablename*")]
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can also use

```
[DataTable("*tableName*")]
```

To define the name of the Azure Mobile Service table to which the data type corresponds.